# Occaisonal black screen on boot AMD A8-4500M laptop

Tags: release-freya, amd, hp

Half of the time when I turn on my laptop I get a black screen.<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> also shows a black screen.I have to put my laptop to sleep and back on to get the screen to work.When my screen is not black I see a message before boot for about a second relating to the radeon driver and then it boots correctly

I am running default drivers with kernel 4.4 installed. The laptop is a HP Pavilion g7 2269wm

Output of `dmesg | grep -i radeon` when screen is **NOT** black

```
[    0.194197] smpboot: CPU0: AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics (family: 0x15, model: 0x10, stepping: 0x1)
[    6.062500] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    6.080879] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[    6.082067] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    6.082075] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[    6.082382] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[    6.082385] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    6.082865] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    6.083172] radeon 0000:00:01.0: Direct firmware load for radeon/TAHITI_vce.bin failed with error -2
[    6.083181] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon_vce: Can't load firmware "radeon/TAHITI_vce.bin"
[    6.091893] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[    6.091897] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355c0c00
[    6.092713] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001835a18
[    6.092717] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VCE init error (-22).
[    6.092723] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355c0c04
[    6.092726] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355c0c08
[    6.092729] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800355c0c0c
[    6.092732] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355c0c10
[    6.092739] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    6.092910] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    6.093191] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    7.275570] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[    8.295553] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[    9.315552] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   10.335549] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   11.355546] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   12.375543] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   13.395541] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   14.415540] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   15.435537] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   16.455535] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!
[   16.475537] [drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, giving up!!!
[   16.475607] [drm:cayman_startup [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed initializing VCE (-1).
[   16.521446] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[   16.521450] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   17.333968] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   18.239239] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   18.306279] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
```

I have tried `nomodeset` . It works but causes the laptop to be slow and heat up

Comment: You can see this message with "dmesg | grep -i radeon". Share the output to more info

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My laptop is UEFI so I use rEFInd.The problem was that rEFInd was loading GRUB which caused some issues.I made rEFInd directly boot elementary OS (using EFI Stub) without GRUB and the problem went away.I could also use secure boot now